# workload impact of IDbCommandInterceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interceptor

The implementation of IDbCommandInterceptor seems to have caused an incredible  high workload on our production server (from +-20% to +80%).

The funny thing is that nothing was being done in the interception. The first idea was to add tracing to the SQL that Entity Framework was generating so we could easily follow up in monitoring tools which action created the SQL. This was done by adding a part of the call stack to the SQL as a comment, but this seemed to cause an extreme workload on the server so that code was put in comment, leaving an empty class as shown below.

I didn't remove the interceptor from the context since I thought it would not have any impact, but apparently it has. Does anyone have any idea why this has such a huge impact?

```
public class EntitiesDbInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {

        }

        public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            AddSourceTracingToSqlQuery(command);
        }

        public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {

        }

        public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            AddSourceTracingToSqlQuery(command);
        }

        public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {

        }

        public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            AddSourceTracingToSqlQuery(command);
        }

        private void AddSourceTracingToSqlQuery(DbCommand dbCommand)
        {
            //try
            //{
            //    var builder = new StringBuilder();

            //    var stack = new StackTrace(true);
            //    builder.Append("\r\n\r\n/********************* \r\n\r\n Entity Framework source trace: \r\n\r\n * ");
            //    var formattedStackTrace = string.Join("\r\n * ",
            //                                             from f in stack.GetFrames().Skip(2)
            //                                             let m = f?.GetMethod()
            //                                             where f?.GetFileLineNumber() != 0
            //                                             select m?.DeclaringType?.Name + "." + m?.Name + ":" + f?.GetFileLineNumber()

            //                                          );
            //    builder.Append(formattedStackTrace);


            //    builder.Append("\r\n*********************/\r\n\r\n");

            //    dbCommand.CommandText = builder.ToString() + dbCommand.CommandText;
            //}
            //catch (Exception)
            //{

            //    throw;
            //}

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did removing it remove the impact? Did you test that to verify?

Comment: yes, removing it seems to have brought CPU loads back to normal levels. Will have a definitive answer in about 3h when most users are active, but compared to same time yesterday workload is -50%.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem.
Using the interceptor every ware increase the usage of cp on about  X4 times.
The  only solution was to use the interceptor only in operation where we really know to need to use the interceptor.

```
 public DevEntities(string connectionstring, bool useInterceptor )
           : base(connectionstring)
 {
    if(useInterceptor )
    {
       DbInterception.Add(new CommandInterceptor());
    }
 }
```